# How do I detect phasing and prevent it when doubling vocals?

Tags: phase

I'm referring to "artificial" doubling using the waves doubler. How many ms delay do I need to prevent phasing in mono? If I delay by 8ms on both the left and right side is that past the phasing threshold?

Comment: Why don't you just experiment and find a setting that works for you?

Comment: With artificial doubling, trial and error worked best for me, natural phasing with instruments are those for which trial and error isnt efficient

Answer (score 3):

Only just, but you're still in dangerous territory if that's a fixed offset. I'd call 8ms somewhere between phase & flange distance. You're still definitely inside comb-filtering. Right up to 20ms could be considered 'chorusing'. These terms are all a bit flexible in reality.

Something like 15 or 20ms might be better; even longer if you're subtle with it, though I wouldn't fix an offset for any kind of ADT effect, I'd play with modulating the delay, which will not only make the time-period alter over time, but also the pitch of the DT itself. Flatter as it slows & sharper as it speeds. The more you push your initial delay, the more you can push the LFO mod on it.

BTW, delaying 'the same on both sides' is just a mono delay, in effect.